# I'm having trouble with a dataset I created using a stored procedure. syntax is below and the error is "error converting datatype varchar to datetime"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

I recently created a stored procedure for reporting services purposes. I tested it in SQL Server, and all was working till I got an error last night after linking my dataset to the stored procedure. The error says

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

I couldn't figure out where in the syntax did I mess up...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_LoansProcessed_ToDate]    '11/14/2021'
    @ReportDate Datetime,
    @LoanAmount varchar(max) = NULL,
    @LoanPurpose varchar(max) = NULL,
    @PropertyUsage varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Demographics2 varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReportDates datetime = '11/14/2021',
            @DayOfWeek varchar(100),
            @BeginOfWeek Datetime,
            @BeginOfMonth Datetime,
            @BeginOfYear Datetime

    SET @DayOfWeek = (SELECT DATENAME(dw, @ReportDates))
    SET @BeginOfWeek = (SELECT      
                            CASE    
                               WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Monday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -2, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Wednesday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -3, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Thursday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -4, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Friday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -5, @ReportDates)
                                WHEN @DayOfWeek = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(dd, -6, @ReportDates) 
                            END BeginOfWeek)

    SET @BeginOfMonth = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(MM, @ReportDates)) + '/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(YY, @ReportDates))))

    SET @BeginOfYear = (SELECT '1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEPART(YY, @ReportDates)))                          

    SELECT      
        b.*,
        d.[martial status], d.Sex, d.Race,
        DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) Age,
        [borrower first name] + ' ' + [borrower last name] BorrowerName,
        [monthly income],
        DATENAME(MONTH, [loan date]) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEPART(YY, [loan date])) FormatedReportMonth,
        CASE 
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfWeek AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates 
                THEN 'WeekToDate'
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfMonth AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates  
                THEN 'MonthToDate'
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfYear AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates 
                THEN 'YearToDate' 
            ELSE NULL 
        END ToDate,
        CASE 
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfWeek AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates 
                THEN 1
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfMonth AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates  
                THEN 2
            WHEN [loan date] >= @BeginOfYear AND [loan date] <= @ReportDates 
                THEN 3 
            ELSE NULL 
        END ToDateOrder,
        CASE 
            WHEN [loan amount] <= 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k'
            WHEN [loan amount] between 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k'
            WHEN [loan amount] > 200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
        END LoanAmountGroup,
        CASE 
            WHEN [loan amount] <= 100000 THEN 1
            WHEN [loan amount] between 100000 AND 200000 THEN 2
            WHEN [loan amount] > 200000 THEN 3 
        END LoanAmountGroupOrder,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) < 25 THEN '<=25'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 THEN '26-35'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN '36-45'   
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) > 45 THEN '46+' 
        END AgeGroup,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) < 25 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) BETWEEN 25 AND 35 THEN 2
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) BETWEEN 36 AND 45 THEN 3
            WHEN DATEDIFF(YY, d.[date of birth], @ReportDates) > 45 THEN 4 
        END AgeGroupOrder   
        --INTO      #Financials   
    FROM        
        [dbo].[fact_financials] a
    LEFT JOIN   
        [dbo].[dim_loan info] b ON a.[loan ID] = b.[loan ID]
    LEFT JOIN   
        [dbo].[dim_property info] c ON a.[loan ID] = c.[loan ID]
    LEFT JOIN   
        [dbo].[dim_borrower info] d ON a.[loan ID] = d.[loan ID]
    WHERE       
        [loan date] <= @ReportDates
END
```

Comment: For all dates in 2021 , I can confirm the date calculations you perform do not generate an error. Therefore, the error lies in the large SELECT statement. `SELECT * FROM dbo.fact_financials...WHERE [loan date] <= @reportDates` Does that work? If not, then you know that there is a mismatch in data type between [loan date] and a datetime. If  loan date is a datetime type, then [date of birth] must be the offending field

Comment: Step 1 - get rid of the parameters your code doesn't use -even if just for posting purposes. That only adds confusion and distraction. A good developer should know to remove clutter. Step 2 - stop using implicit conversion of dates to strings to manipulate them. Why do you cast the year of a date to varchar(100)? You're just not thinking or trying much. For that matter, why is everything a "datetime" and not "date"? You've developed bad habits - time to drop those and develop good habits.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_LoansProcessed_ToDate]    '11/14/2021'` This first line is not valid. Your attempt to create the procedure will fail - so this code as posted seems to be different from what you actually run. Generally speaking, you should use a date format that is always understood correctly by the database engine - suggest '20211114' (YYYYMMDD).

Comment: DATEFROMPARTS can be easily used to get the first of the current month or the Jan 1 of the current year. No string conversion needed.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I’m a  beginner so ill make this adjustments for sure! i changed the data type like you said and it worked.